# How can I type the currency symbol for Costa Rican colón on my Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On OS X, how can I type the [Costa Rican colón](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Rican_col%C3%B3n)?

<sub>The symbol is:</sub>

## ₡

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Add it to the Press & Hold character picker

You can add it to a letter's Press & Hold character picker.

1. Navigate to `System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`.
2. Backup the `Keyboard-en.plist` file.
3. Append the following to the `Keyboard-en.plist` file (before the closing `</dict></plist>`).

   ```xml
   <key>Roman-Accent-w</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Direction</key>
       <string>right</string>
       <key>Keycaps</key>
       <string>₡</string>
       <key>Strings</key>
       <string>₡</string>
   </dict>
   ```

Feel free to change the `Roman-Accent-w` to any character you wish, providing it does not already have Press & Hold keys assigned.

[image]

If you wish to use a character with an existing Press & Hold set, you can append the `₡` to the relevant `<string>` lines for that character.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Edit → Special Characters (or press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>).
2. Click on the gear wheel at top left and select **Customize List…**, then check the box for **Currency Symbols**.

   [image]
3. Select **Currency Symbols** from the list and find the one you want.  Double-click it to enter it at the current insertion point, or drag-drop it to the desired location.

   [image]

Answer (score -2):

you can use this key combination alt 0162 ¢

Comment: this is a question about OSX, not Windows. And anyway, that is a ¢ not the character asked for, ₡.

Comment: As wrong as an answer can get, should be deleted.